# What are the dimensions, angles of a Gibson Les Paul standard pots cavity?

Tags: guitar, lutherie

I am working on building a prewired set of pots and want to mount them on a piece of plastic that can drop into the cavity of a standard les paul. I have been looking for the dimensions and found this image:

[image: https://i.pinimg.com/originals/b5/b9/92/b5b9923a3ecd697492969bf84dd9b2c7.jpg]

But the image is too blurry to make out what the measurements say. If someone knows or can provide the distances between each shaft hole, and the diameter of the round bored out cavity one of the four pots get installed in, I can figure out the necessary angles from there.

Comment: Why don't you enlarge the images until they're life sized? Might need to do some paper folding, but It'd get there.

Comment: I don't have a les paul to compare it to. Otherwise, I would just take the measurements directly.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Schemtics are tricky, there's 3 things you can do:

1. [This link](https://www.electricherald.com/gibson-les-paul-guitar-templates/) contains many blue prints of a Gibson Les Paul. There are no measurements on each axis. However, on each PDF there is a scale. Use the scale as a reference point, print out the diagrams and use a ruler to get exact sizing. Easy!
2. [This photo](http://www.greasygroove.com/images/dimensions/LPCavityCov.jpg) contains scaling for the cavity and POT's however the radius of the POT's must be taken into consideration as seen [here](http://www.latesixtieslespauls.com/images/first_68_cavity.jpg).
3. Try emailing Gibson for shcemtics, there shouldn't be any issues (worth a shot).

When you're making your pre-wired kit, make sure to solder all the cables off the POT's into the centre of cavity so that the cables are not facing the wood of the cavity which will cause placement issues. Common and silly mistake that I learnt the hard way.

Comment: Thank you for these ideas. I ordered a jig and I've been playing with it over my screen in inkscape. So far, I'm fascinated to learn that the shaft hole alignments are not a symmetrical rhombus as I expected. Nor are they even a symmetrical trapezoid. I'm going to compare the jig I have with the PDFs. Once I have precise measurements, I'll add them here as a comment and accept the answer.

Comment: This has exactly what I needed: https://www.electricherald.com/diagrams/lespaul/Gibson-Les-Paul-1950s.pdf

Comment: Awesome! Glad you made use of it.

Comment: This still doesn't seem to be adding up. Have the measurements changed between a 1950 and modern LP? I have a 22mm wide speed knob. When I draw a circle 22mm wide in inkscape, it's a perfect match. But when I use the 1950 dimensions in inkscape, my jig doesn't line up.  I think I'm doing something wrong, so I'm keeping this accepted as an answer

Comment: Make sure the scale is still accurate after printing the diagrams, if it's not you'll just measure the scale and do some easy algebra for making your own scale. Seriously while you're trying to work all this out it will be worth a shot of emailing Gibson.